# Using gulp.series with a gulp task that has a callback

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to use `gulp.series` to generate all my build assets at once for CircleCI.

```
const circleciBuild = gulp.series(styles, js, generate-favicon)
```

`lando gulp circleciBuild` fails with the message:

```
ReferenceError: generate is not defined
```

But it is defined in the gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('generate-favicon', function(done) {
  realFavicon.generateFavicon({
  // Long function
  }, function() {
    done();
  });
```

});

I tried changing the function's name to `generateTheFavicon`, but then I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: generateTheFavicon is not defined
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the way the task is defined, because `js` and `styles` are `function js()` and `function styles()`, whereas the problem function is `gulp.task`.  How can I rewrite a `gulp.task` function to use it in `gulp.series`?

This might be easy, but I'm new to gulp and not very good with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using this style of defining tasks:

```
gulp.task('generate-favicon',...
```

Then you will always refer to those tasks as their string names.  So

```
const circleciBuild = gulp.series(styles, js, 'generate-favicon')
```

You don't show your other tasks so I don't know how they are defined.

If instead you used this form:

```
function generate-favicon ()  {...
```

then you wouldn't refer to them as strings, just their function names so

```
const circleciBuild = gulp.series(styles, js, generate-favicon)
```

would be correct.  For other reasons, like passing arguments this later function name method is the recommended way to do it.